# Console.log() does not output to remote debugger for Awesomium in C++

Tags: javascript, c++, google-chrome, debugging, awesomium

I am using [Awesomium library](http://www.awesomium.com/) for UI of my C++ application ("plain" C++, no .NET, precompiled headers etc.).

Everything works fine, I am able to send events from C++ application to JavaScript in Awesomium and vice versa. UI responds to clicks etc. thanks to `webCore->Update()`.

The problem is, sometimes errors in JavaScript occurs. And I would like to see them like in e.g. Edge/Chrome/Firefox (where you can press F12 to see console, debugger etc.).

I know that it's possible to use remote debugger for Awesomium with appropriate `WebConfig` so I've tried:

```
Awesomium::WebConfig webConfig;
webConfig.remote_debugging_host = Awesomium::WSLit("127.0.0.1");
webConfig.remote_debugging_port = 9222;
//create the WebCore singleton with configuration
webCore = Awesomium::WebCore::Initialize(webConfig);

//create a new WebView instance with a certain width and height
view = webCore->CreateWebView(width, height, 0, Awesomium::kWebViewType_Window);
view->set_parent_window(*windowHandle->getHWND());

view->set_view_listener(this);

//create a global js object named 'app'
Awesomium::JSValue result = view->CreateGlobalJavascriptObject(Awesomium::WSLit("app"));

//bind our method dispatcher to the WebView
view->set_js_method_handler(this);

if (result.IsObject()) {
    //bind our custom method to it
    Awesomium::JSObject& appObject = result.ToObject();
    appObject.SetCustomMethod(Awesomium::WSLit("sendEvent"), false);
}
```

Now in Chrome at `http://localhost:9222/#` I see my session:
[image]

I am able to e.g. select UI elements inside my C++ application with debugger.
**But I cannot see anything in my debugger's console tab in Chrome** (I do use `console.log("Hello!")` inside website that is loaded into Awesomium):
[image]

p.s. The debugger window is not 100% height (as you see on screen). Can I fix it somehow?

p.s.2. Google Chrome is not my browser of choice. Can I use another one for debugging Awesomium UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript error/debug messages are not visible in the remote debugger of Awesomium (v1.7.5.1).
The only way I found was by listening to the `OnAddConsoleMessage()` method in the `WebViewListener::Load` class. 
You have to make your own subclass and register it to your webview.

```
    #include <Awesomium/WebViewListener.h>
    class MyViewListender : public WebViewListener::View {

            // ... All the overridden WebViewListener::View methods go here

            void OnAddConsoleMessage(Awesomium::WebView* caller,
                                     const Awesomium::WebString& message,
                                     int line_number,
                                     const Awesomium::WebString& source) 
            {
                    cout << "Console: " << message << endl;
            }
    };
```

Register it:

```
    MyViewListender* my_view_listener = new MyViewListender();
    view->set_view_listener(my_view_listener);
```